# Unable to run java program in current directory

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java program in current directory

I executed the ff. commands in current directory where the class file is HelloJNI.class, but it just doesn't work

```
java HelloJNI
```

and

```
java -cp . HelloJNI
```

Both commands doesn't work.

[image]

I also tried setting the CLASSPATH variable and it still doesn't work. Searched a lot but still have no idea.

[image]

The error says could not find class HelloJNI. I really can't understand why

------------- EDIT -------------------

```
package com.greetings;

public class HelloJNI 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      System.out.println("Whatever");
   }
}
```

adding the package name also results in same error:

[image]

Comment: Appears like `HelloJNI` does not have a main method. How does you class look like?

Comment: Does your code use a `package`?

Comment: @hotzst yes, I have a main method. The code is a pretty much a "Hello World" code.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I do, have a package. And I also tried appending the package name, but still the same. See added screenshot

Comment: If the correct folders aren't being created, try the `-d` option: `javac -d . HelloJNI.java` And run with `java com.greetings.HelloJNI`

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile the Java code? For example:

javac

> javac HelloJNI.java

Then you can run (if there are no compile errors).

> java HelloJNI

I suggest using Maven or Gradle to build, test, lint etc your Java code. It will help greatly with dependency management and with a reproducible build on other operating systems and on CI/CD systems such as Jenkins and GitLab.

Comment: Hi, yes I did compile it. I already shown the list of items in current directory provided in the screenshot. Its just a plain simple java "Hello World" type project. The project can be ran in Eclipse. I posted the code.